# Changing spatialpolygonsdataframe to default longitude/latitude (degrees) using R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, rgdal

I am trying (and failing) to convert the coordinates in a spatial object (Spatialpolygonsdataframe) form easting/northing to latitude/longitude. The zone is 35S.

I know it can be achieved with spTransform, but I am struggling with it:

`sp2 <- spTransform(sp, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m + no_defs"))`

```
summary(sp)

Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min        max
x   68947.1   77921.63
y 9618287.1 9630115.64
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84
+units=m +no_defs]
```

Comment: how does it not work? error messages? what is `sp` object and what coordinate system does it have? does it have one at all? Your code looks like it is transforming `sp` to zone 35, not to lat-long.

Comment: many thanks, Spacedman -- the sp object is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and the CRS is WGS 84 / UTM Zone 35S. that is as far as I got with assigning the CHRS.

yes, I am trying to figure out how to use spTransform to change the coordinates to lat/long. I'm not saying that command above did what I wanted it to :) sorry that was not clear. i feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You assign the CRS to an sp object using `proj4string(d)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")` (eg if your data is in epsg 4326 lat-long. That doesn't change the numbers, it only changes the metadata of the CRS. Then `spTransform` returns a new object with new numbers given by the CRS argument to it. Can you edit your question and show us `summary(sp)` so we can see if it already has a CRS?

Comment: Metadata -- I see. It already has a CRS (I believe) -- as above.

Comment: Now we can see it seems to have the right CRS already, so you need to use `spTransform` to convert to the desired one. See answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given an object `sp` with the correct CRS assigned to it, then:

```
sp2 = spTransform(sp, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

should create a new object in lat-long coordinates given by the WGS84 "GPS" coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you -- that works! Found it interesting that I don't have to enter +proj=longlat as well.

Comment: The EPSG codes are shortcuts for the expanded definitions - EPSG:4326 is "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs". You can look these up at epsg.io and other sites. That also gives the fuller WKT string definition which is even more verbose!